# Snippet gets stuck, requiring an additional keystroke

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

The following snippet gets stuck with an assigned keymap, requiring an extra keystroke for it to appear on screen.

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
{\bf \underline{ ${1:} }}
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

The goal is to have the cursor {\bf \underline{ `stop here` }} when executing the snippet.

Any ideas what is causing this snippet to freeze before appearing on screen, requiring me to use an extra keystroke (e.g., an arrow key)?

Comment: Check out: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Ryan B for the link -- greatly appreciated.  It turned out to be a keymap issue, caused by having `"super+l", "b", "u"` that conflicted with `"super+l", "b", "u", "s"`.  If there is a longer-stringed keymap using the same assignments, then all assignments must be on the same tier to avoid conflicts.  In this case, it was necessary to add a third letter to the first assignment, or choose a completely different assignment.

Comment: You're welcome. I thought you would just need to remove the `{`, but you dug deeper